# Can't install Manuskript on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04

I have tried to install Manuskript on Ubuntu 20.04 and the first time it works. However, one moment later it crashes again and again.

I have uninstalled the application and from this moment the new installation doesn't work.

What's the problem?

Comment: any idea what the crash message you're getting is?

Comment: Do you have the error message? How did you install it? (`apt`, `snap` etc.) and what version of the application are you running? If you launch it via terminal do you get output?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I enable the "Universe" repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have succeeded to install the application but through Synaptic with all the dependencies needed, and it works well. But the installation with Snap was failed.